# Internet is disconnected with Debian squeeze

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am using "debian-squeeze-amd64-root_fs" with `linux-3.18.4` kernel to debug Linux kernel.

The problem is that there is no internet connection in Debian when the Internet is absolutely positively connected.

When I ran

```
ifconfig
```

the only thing I can see is `Local Loopback`

Here's the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# The loopback newtork interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

atuo eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in the second-to-last row: `atuo eth0` should be `auto eth0`, so the system isn't able to bring the network connection up automatically. You might also try running `ifup eth0`, despite the typo.

I'd have guessed the error to appear in the logs as invalid configuration, though.